# Why does git diff --textconv use the path twice?

Tags: git

So I am trying to get a git diff working for sqlite. Basically I want to have git compare the files as if they were text files. In my repository I have a `.gitattributes` file containing this:

```
*.db diff=sqlite3
```

And then in my `.git/config` file I added the following:

```
[diff "sqlite3"]
    textconv = sqlite3 "$1" .dump
```

But this doesn't work. I get an error message:

```
Error: near "/": syntax error
fatal: unable to read files to diff
```

So I tried changing the config to just echo what it gets as input:

```
[diff "sqlite3"]
    textconv = echo "$1"
```

And then I can see the git diff working, but it outputs this:

```
-/var/folders/mn/_1zkhxm93dq787rf0n1p_vyr0000gn/T//blFdBa_database.db /var/folders/mn/_1zkhxm93dq787rf0n1p_vyr0000gn/T//blFdBa_database.db
+path/to/the/database/database.db path/to/the/database/database.db
```

It's the path twice, but I can't seem to find any information on why this is and how I can fix it (without using regexes to split it at the spaces).

I'm on macOS 10.14.3 and `git --version` gives `git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply mechanically replace:

> ```
> textconv = sqlite3 "$1" .dump
> ```

with:

```
textconv = "f(){ sqlite3 \"$1\" .dump; }; f"
```

#### Why

[The `gitattributes` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) says this about `textconv`:

> The program should take a single argument, the name of a file to convert, and produce the resulting text on stdout.

and then gives this as an example:

> ```
>     [diff "jpg"]
>             textconv = exif
> ```

By adding `$1` you have Git run your command with the first argument, and then with the arguments.  The arguments consist of one argument—so you see the one argument twice.  Had the arguments consisted of two strings, you would have seen the first one repeated, then the second one once.

(This behavior is the same as for Git's aliases.)

If you need to run `sqlite3` with *two* arguments, as in `sqlite3 name-of-file .dump`, you must invent an intermediate command that takes *one* argument, as in `command name-of-file`.  That intermediate command can then simply add the final argument.

As with aliases, you can do this with a shell function:

```
[diff "odd"]
    textconv = "f(){ echo $1 extra; }; f"

$ git diff
diff --git a/.gitattributes b/.gitattributes
index 9fa72ad450..bf2ef674cb 100644
--- a/.gitattributes
+++ b/.gitattributes
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 * whitespace=!indent,trail,space
 *.[ch] whitespace=indent,trail,space diff=cpp
-*.sh whitespace=indent,trail,space eol=lf
+*.sh whitespace=indent,trail,space eol=lf diff=odd
 *.perl eol=lf diff=perl
 *.pl eof=lf diff=perl
 *.pm eol=lf diff=perl
diff --git a/check-builtins.sh b/check-builtins.sh
index a0aaf3a347..089031a86e 100755
--- a/check-builtins.sh
+++ b/check-builtins.sh
@@ -1 +1 @@
-/tmp/fo3NBV_check-builtins.sh extra
+check-builtins.sh extra
```